# How return value from async function in before in mocha and use same value in same describe in function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Faced with the problem when writing code. I want to reduce the amount of code used in the tests, but there are problems.

I have test, but he don't worked:

```
var repeatTests = function(value){

    it ('test1 use value', function(done){
        console.log (value) // return undefined
        ...
    }

    it ('test2 use value', function(done){
       console.log (value) // return undefined
        ...
}

    ...

}

describe ('test', function(){

    var _value
    before(function(done){

        asyncFunction(function(err, value){
            ...    
            _value = value
            ...
            done();
        }

    })

    repeatTests(_value) // value is undefined


})
```

But this worked:

```
describe ('test', function(){

    var _value
    before(function(done){

        asyncFunction(function(err, value){
            ...
            _value = value
            ...

            done();
        }

    })

    it ('test1 use value', function(done){
        console.log(_value); // return _value
        ...
    }

    it ('test2 use value', function(done){
        console.log(_value); // return _value
        ...
    }

        ...


})
```

I know why this is happening. Please tell me, how do I implement the first version of the test.

Answer (score 0):

The repeatTests function is invoked at the same time as the before and so will always be undefined.

Comment: Thank you, i edited question. I try with done() and without done(), but test don't working.

Comment: try wrapping the `repeatTest(_value)` in a describe block

Comment: thinking about it; I'm not convinced this is possible. The `repeatTests` function is invoked at the same time as the `before` and so will always be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe wanna use `async.waterfall`. It would looks like this:

```
var repeatTests = function(value){

    it ('test1 use value', function(done){
        console.log (value) // return undefined
        ...
    }

    it ('test2 use value', function(done){
       console.log (value) // return undefined
        ...
}

    ...

}

describe ('test', function(){

    var _value

    async.waterfall([
       before(function(done){

        asyncFunction(function(err, value){
            ...    
            _value = value
            ...
            done();
        }

    }),
    async.apply(repeatTests,_value) //Apply for passing the parameter to the repeatTests function
    ], 
    function(err){
       console.log('End of all');
    }
})
```

Comment: It don't work. If `it('it', function(done){})` in async function - mocha don't use this `it`.